# Cannot push with Netbeans and GIT on Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: git, netbeans, amazon-ec2

I'm pretty new on UNIX/GIT world.

I'm trying to setup a GIT repo on a Amazon EC2 Machine so I can work on my projects from different places with ease.

After some hours of work some things are ok, I managed to connect to the repo with my IDE (Netbeans) and clone the remote content.

The problem start when I try to push something to the remote repo, Netbeans give me an error and this output, with a generic error:

```
==[IDE]== 4-lug-2012 15.34.59 Pushing
git push ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/myDir/        +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : 84c3fb34b54b501b52c914eca123d4d850688e26
New Id : 7e7fd752d2cde7b0bf8824eef83c535ee2418508
Result : REJECTED_OTHER_REASON

Local Repository Updates
Branch : origin/master
Old Id : 84c3fb34b54b501b52c914eca123d4d850688e26
New Id : 7e7fd752d2cde7b0bf8824eef83c535ee2418508
Result : NOT_ATTEMPTED

==[IDE]== 4-lug-2012 15.35.02 Pushing finished.
```

I've read around about make the remote depo "bare", the git push succeed in this case but the file isn't updated anyway... what I'm missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it work from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your EC2 instance also where your code is used for production? If so, then you'll need a bare repository on your EC2 instance to handle the commits and another git clone (of the bare repository) to provide your production code.

Work flow:

1. Set-up a bare repository on your EC2 instaance.
2. Clone this for your production code*
3. Clone this new repository to your local machine*
4. Code, Commit, Push. Repeat.
5. Configure a [post-receive](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook to automatically update your production (eg, pull)

*Obviously you don't want the pull to update your production with HEAD/master - so ensure that you've got a branch/tag for production or for development.

Comment: Yes my EC2 istance is also my production code at this moment. Your solution sounds reasonable, but how shall I configure the git clone to update it in an efficent way? There is a better way to pull from the master repo everytime? Thanks.

Comment: If i try to pull manually I'm getting this error: 
`error: Your local changes to 'path/to/file.php' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.`

But, if I'm not mistaken, you can't commit a bare repo?

Comment: That sounds like you're making changes in multiple places.

Comment: Ok, I've got just one last question: why is important to update my production repo with a HEAD different from master?

Comment: It is if you're using the hooks to update your production. You'll not want all your pushed code going automatically to production with going through some staging process / testing.

Comment: Ok I understand that but I'm little confused about how to proceed. I have to clone the production repo but to push the new files to the bare repo, right? So i have to create a "development" branch for the production repo? I have to clone this branch or the master on my local machine? Because if I clone the development one I get an error when trying to push the update on the bare repo...

Comment: Let's just stick with master for now. Clone the bare repository to your local machine and develop. Don't use any hooks to update production. When you're happy with the code on your local machine, push back to the bare repository. Then pull from the production, which should grab from the bare repository also.

Comment: Well I think this is the best way for now, one small step at time, thanks again for all, have a nice day! :D